# Insert an image at the end of a doc and then convert it into docx with vbs

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, docx

My code almost work... but I have a problem to insert image at the end of a doc.
The objective of this vbs script is :

1. To insert an image at the end of the document
2. to convert this document from doc to docx

```
bRecursive = False
PicPath = "C:\toto\signature.jpg"
sFolder = "C:\toto"
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
ConvertFolder(oFolder)
oWord.Quit

Sub ConvertFolder(oFldr)
    For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
        If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "doc" Then
            Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.path)

        Set r1 = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToLast)
            r1.InlineShapes(1).Select
            Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=PicPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs oFile.path & "x", 12
            oDoc.Close
        End If
    Next

    If bRecursive Then
        For Each oSubfolder In oFldr.Subfolders
            ConvertFolder oSubfolder
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you do any research? Like looking up the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.goto)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub ConvertFolder(oFldr)
    For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
        If LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "doc" Then
            Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)
            oDoc.Range.InsertAfter vbCr
            oDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=PicPath, LinkToFile:=False, _
                SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=oDoc.Range.Characters.Last
            oDoc.SaveAs oFile.Path & "x", 12
            oDoc.Close
        End If
    Next

    If bRecursive Then
        For Each oSubfolder In oFldr.Subfolders
            ConvertFolder oSubfolder
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```